# Where best to store an array of strings in an Android application?

Tags: android

For my Android application, users will be able to generate a  number of strings (for example favourite search terms) and have them displayed in a ListView.  I would like this ListView to be saved, so when the user launches the application again the list of favourite search terms for instance is still displayed.  I am unsure which method of storage would be best for this scenario.

options:
1. Shared Preferences
2. Internal Storage
3. SQLite database.

Any suggestions on the most efficient way to accomplish this would be really appreciated.

Comment: it depends on your usage and needs, If its small text and you use it just for display go for shared preferences, If its quite big and just used for display and no other manipulation go for storage in files, if you are gonna manipulate on them go for database

Comment: I am hoping to store and display strings like: "apoptosis and cancer", "Neuroblastoma in child infancy" etc...in ListView. I won't be manipulating them.

Comment: as i said, depends on the total length of all the strings that are gonna be stored, and also on their usage

Answer (score 1):

As mr: Panther said "It depends on your usage and needs".

1. If its a small amount of data like key-value pair you can use **sharedprefrence**. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist across user sessions (even if your application is killed).
2. You can save files directly on the device's **internal storage**. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.
3. Android provides full support for **SQLite databases**. Any databases you create will be accessible by name to any class in the application, but not outside the application.

In this 3 options the data will erased while uninstallation of the application. If you want the data globally for your app, You can store it in server(or use something like MySql). Still you want to know more visit [Storage Options | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)